# docker - using python image, add the non-free Debian repo?

Tags: python, docker, debian

Im using a python image in docker and have added some dependencies as per the below:

```
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils libsasl2-dev python3-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev libsnmp-dev snmp-mibs-downloader
```

I'm getting an error

```
E: Package 'snmp-mibs-downloader' has no installation candidate
```

Which after searching is because I need a non-free repo adding as per: http://installion.co.uk/debian/wheezy/non-free/s/snmp-mibs-downloader/install/index.html

I believe I need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add the below:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

but how do I do that via a docker file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you would do to add the `non-free` component to your `sources.list`. Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in your Dockerfile and replace the line that looks like:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
```

by

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

You can do that in the Dockerfile with a command like

```
sed -i "s#deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free#deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free#g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And same for `security.debian.org`.

Comment: sed: can't read /etc/apt/source.list: No such file or directory. Probably worth mentioning that I'm using python base image, does that have a difference sources file?

Comment: I made a typo, I think it's `sources` (plural)

Answer (score 17):

While this is the right command,

```
sed -i -e's/ main/ main contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you're going to do this you should do this as part of the rest of your first-image,

```
RUN \
  sed -i -e's/ main/ main contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get -q update                                              \
  && apt-get -qy dist-upgrade                                       \
  && apt-get install -qy foobar                                     \
  && foobar whatever                                                \
  && apt-get -qy --purge remove foobar                              \
  && apt-get clean                                                  \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
```

The above shows this command in the full flow with the rest of the `apt` stuff.

Comment: thanks for posting the version agnostic script variant

Answer (score 0):

You can use any script that the other answers provide.
I just made some testing with sed.
This sed works for me:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s/ main[[:space:]]*\$/ main contrib non-free/" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Basically it matches 'main', spaces and end of line.
Which basically means that main is the last repo in the line.
If it matches it adds the contrib and non-free at the end.
If you want to test it, remove the -i to edit in-place.

The good thing of this sed it's that it doesn't repeat repos when used repeatedly.
So there is no chance of having duplicate repos.